# Can I only call a function from the terminal rather the whole bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a bash script that looks as such:

```
#!/bin/bash

function one {
    echo "I am function one!!"
}

function two {
    echo "I am function two!!"
}

one
two
```

If I simply do *bash test.sh* both functions are being executed.

What I'd like to do is to call the script from the terminal while also specifying one of the two functions, and executing only it.
Maybe something like: *bash test.sh$one()* and it should only print out

> I am function one!!

Is this possible and if so, how will I go about achieving it?

Thanks!

=========================

**EDIT:** As per @Waqas suggestion I ended up implementing the below which did the trick for me:

```
function main {
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        some commands
    # else run the given function only
    else
        $1
    fi
}
main "$@"
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: There is no mechanism for this, but you could hack something together that parses the script and extracts only one function. However, the right way would probably be an additional file where you define the functions but do not execute them, then `source` that file to make the functions available OR adapt the script to behave differently depending on its arguments.

Comment: not with `()`'s but witout you can simply replace the calls to the funcs with `$@`, then call like `bash test.sh one`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to write the code in order to fulfill your requirement. The way I will write the code for this, is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
function main {
    # If the argument is empty then run both functions else only run provided function as argument $1.
    [ -z "$1" ] && { one; two; } || $1     
}
        
function one {    
    echo "I am function one!!"    
}
    
function two {    
    echo "I am function two!!"    
}
    
main "$@"
```

If you only execute the script without passing argument then both functions will run and with passing argument only single function will work.

Example1 (Both functions will run): bash script_name

Example2 (Only function one will run): bash script_name one

Example3 (Only function two will run): bash script_name two

Comment: Thank you, this was the method I ended up implementing and it did exactly what I was after. I had to edit the code a bit as I couldn't get it working with the one-liner you referenced.

Answer (score 1):

You better separate the files: Move the function definitions in a separate file, say `~/lib/testlib.src`. Your test.sh then becomes

```
#!/bin/bash
. ~/lib/testlib.src
one
two
```

If you need the definitions in your interactive shell, either do there a `. ~/lib/testlib.src` manually, or if you want to have them always available, put this statement into your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Hi, I've seen this being suggested before. Trying to separate the into a file holding your functions and a second one sourcing the functions file and calling them from there.

Is there any reason why having everything in one *"master"* script isn't *best*-practice?

Comment: Tedious to do. To include the functions in your shell, you would have t source the master script, which means that the body (which is unrelated to the function definitions) would be executed. Since we usually don't want this, we would have to ask explicitly in the "master" script, whether we are being sourced or not.

Comment: @carlitobrigante: The other alternative would be that you devote the whole master script **solely** to the invocation of the functions. This is possible and may make sense, but from a design perspective, you are not invoking _functions_ anymore, but _sub commands_. Technically speaking, the master script could implement a subcommand in any way it likes, not necessarily by calling a function. This approach is taken when you are using i.e. `git` or `svn`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by writing a case statement after defining the functions but before any other lines of code.

```
#!/bin/bash

function one {
    echo "I am function one!!"
}

function two {
    echo "I am function two!!"
}

case $1 in
  one)
    one
  ;;
  two)
    two
  ;;
  *)
    one
    two
  ;;
esac
```

Which could then be used as:

```
$ ./test.sh one
# I am function one!!

$ ./test.sh two
# I am function two!!
```

In the above example I put the body of your script under the *) option, but if it better suits your needs, you could instead have the one) and two) options "exit" after calling their single function:

```
case $1 in
  one)
    one
    exit 0
  ;;
  two)
    two
    exit 0
  ;;
esac

one
two
```

This is all assuming you are not passing any other arguments to the script and that $1 would be used for the desired function. The case statement would become more complex otherwise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I ended up implementing another solution but this is indeed also one neat workaround you've shared!